# How to prevent data loss in persistent volume when server is recreated

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-openstack

I am working with terraform and openstack and using a persistent volume to store data. When recreating the server only and reattaching the same vol, this data is sometimes corrupted/lost. How do i prevent this?

I taint the server and then terraform apply to recreate. This detaches the vol , destroys the server, recreates and attaches back the volume. However, sometimes the data in the volume is lost or corrupted. This vol contains postgreSQL DB files.

I tried to use terraform destroy - but that will cause the volume to be destroyed as well.

This is the module

```
data "template_file" "init-config" {
  template = "${file("modules/postgres-server/init-config.tpl")}"

  vars {
    instance_name = "${var.instance_name}"
    tenant_name   = "${var.tenant_name}"
  }
}

# Define instance properties.
# You should provide the variables in main.tf
resource "openstack_compute_instance_v2" "server" {
  name            = "${var.instance_name}"
  image_name      = "${var.image_name}"
  flavor_name     = "${var.flavor_name}"
  key_pair        = "${var.key_name}"
  security_groups = ["default", "${var.secgroup_name}"]
  user_data       = "${data.template_file.init-config.rendered}"
  stop_before_destroy = "true"

  network {
        name = "${var.tenant_name}-net"
  }
}

# Define a floating ip resoruce
resource "openstack_networking_floatingip_v2" "server_float" {
  pool = "net-iaas-external-dev"
}

# Associate the instance and floating ip resources
resource "openstack_compute_floatingip_associate_v2" "server_float_assoc" {
  floating_ip = "${openstack_networking_floatingip_v2.server_float.address}"
  instance_id = "${openstack_compute_instance_v2.server.id}"
}

# Create persistent vol
resource "openstack_blockstorage_volume_v2" "pgvol" {
  name = "postgreSQL-DATA-${var.instance_name}"
  description = "Data Vol for ${var.instance_name}"
  size = 50
}

# Attach the persistent data to the instance
resource "openstack_compute_volume_attach_v2" "pgvol_attach" {
  instance_id = "${openstack_compute_instance_v2.server.id}"
  volume_id = "${openstack_blockstorage_volume_v2.pgvol.id}"
  device = "/dev/vdc"
}
```

This is the main.tf

```
module "postgre-server" {
  source = "./modules/postgres-server"

  instance_name = "INST_NAME"
  image_name    = "centos7"
  flavor_name   = "r1.medium"
  key_name      = "${module.keypair.output_key_name}"
  secgroup_name = "${module.secgroup.output_secgroup_name}"
  tenant_name   = "${var.tenant_name}"
}
```

Expected result is that volume data is not lost and when I attached back to the newly re-created server, the filesystems in that volume and all the data is there.

Thanks. Appreciate any insights on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

A quick way is to split code into two stacks, one stack (module #1) manages the storage only, the other (module #2) manage the rest.

After split, you can change module #2 anytime, whatever apply or destroy.

Between two stacks, you can reference storage resource with several ways.

#### Way one:

reference from data source [terraform_remote_state](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/terraform/d/remote_state.html), which you need set an output as below

```
output "persistant_storage_id" {
  value = "${openstack_blockstorage_volume_v2.pgvol.id}"
}
```

then use below code in module 2 to reference the persistent storage.

```
data "terraform_remote_state" "persistent_storage" {
  backend = "xxx"
  config {
    name = "hashicorp/persistent-storage"
  }
}
```

so module #2 can reference it as `${data.terraform_remote_state.persistent_storage.persistent_storage_id}"`

#### Way two:

reference persistent storage volume id with data source [openstack_blockstorage_availability_zones_v3](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/openstack/d/blockstorage_availability_zones_v3.html) directly

#### way three:

way #3 is similar as #1.

you need output the value `"${openstack_blockstorage_volume_v2.pgvol.id}"` in module #1,

```
output "persistant_storage_id" {
  value = "${openstack_blockstorage_volume_v2.pgvol.id}"
}
```

call the module #1

```
module "persistent_storage" {
   ...
}
```

then reference it as `${module.persistent_storage.persistent_storage_id}"`

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. While they should consider splitting their Terraform code to make it simpler to replace the instance and not the storage that's not what they're struggling with.

Comment: after split, you can run on module #2 anytime, whatever apply or destroy

Comment: the main issue for me is that data is missing after the instance is recreated. I have 3 partitions on the vol, but after reattach, sometimes they are there, sometimes they are missing.. sometimes they are there but corrupted. 

have been testing further - and if i stop the instance and detach the vol with openstack commands before i destroy the instance and recreate, my data is there after reattach of vol. I can't be 100% sure without more testing. I'm trying to avoid this though - as would prefer to have terraform run all this

Answer (score 0):

This is working when I unmount the filesystems in the vol prior to using terraform to recreate the instance. I thought the stop_before_destroy = "true" would have gracefully stopped the instance and detach vol, but it didn't work in my case :)